# How Are You Finding The Visual Studio 2022 Project Properties Window

Tags: visual-studio

Having just installed Visual Studio 2022, I am having a hard time getting my head around the new revamped project properties window.

Just to change the App name seems like a maze. Is anyone else finding it hard to navigate around the new window ?

Comment: it is in the project file. if your app name is different from project name, you need to specify it

Comment: Would this be the Assembly Name

Comment: yes------------------